# Tensorflow + Bazel save configuration to compile on another machine

Tags: tensorflow, compilation, bazel

Trying to build Tensorflow from sources, I wanted to optimize it for a specific CPU (x5-Z8350). However, since I do not know the specific flags to provide to `bazel build`, I simply use the `-march=native` option. The problem is that I need to do the compilation on a different, faster machine.

For reference, the tutorial I follow for the build is Tensorflow's official guide: [Build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

So, I would like to know if there is any way I can get the implicit flags that are used when `-march=native` is set ? Also, is the answer mostly OS-independent ?

Here's the global idea of the steps I have in mind:

1. Run **./configure** on the slow machine (*M1*) and use `-march=native`
2. Run `bazel build [...]` on *M1* to start Tensorflow compilation
3. Save the flags that are used by the compiler
4. Run steps 1 and 2 on the fast machine (*M2*) with the saved compilation flags instead of the default `-march=native`

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_cc_opt_flags(environ_cp):
  """Set up architecture-dependent optimization flags.

  Also append CC optimization flags to bazel.rc..

  Args:
    environ_cp: copy of the os.environ.
  """
  if is_ppc64le():
    # gcc on ppc64le does not support -march, use mcpu instead
    default_cc_opt_flags = '-mcpu=native'
  elif is_windows():
    default_cc_opt_flags = '/arch:AVX'
  else:
    default_cc_opt_flags = '-march=native'
  question = ('Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when'
              ' bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is %s]: '
             ) % default_cc_opt_flags
  cc_opt_flags = get_from_env_or_user_or_default(environ_cp, 'CC_OPT_FLAGS',
                                                 question, default_cc_opt_flags)
  for opt in cc_opt_flags.split():
    write_to_bazelrc('build:opt --copt=%s' % opt)
  # It should be safe on the same build host.
  if not is_ppc64le() and not is_windows():
    write_to_bazelrc('build:opt --host_copt=-march=native')
  write_to_bazelrc('build:opt --define with_default_optimizations=true')
```

As written in **configure.py**, -march=native is a default option:

```
default_cc_opt_flags = '-march=native'
```

So you can just run

```
cd tensorflow
yes "" | ./configure
```

to automatically configure the build using all default options.

And you can check **.tf_configure.bazelrc** to see if

`build:opt --copt=-march=nativ` has been set.

Comment: Yes, you will see `--copt=-march=native` in that file I know, but what I want to know is what flags are being used (native simply tells the compiler to optimize for the current machine).